# How to add people name in share button

Tags: javascript, php, magento, google-api

I am trying to post some content on Google Plus (*which is attached with my current website url*) to my client's website.

---

[image]

---

Here is the code which I tried:

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="none" data-href="http://www.kamlekar.com"></div>

<!-- Place this tag after the last share tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

By using the above code, I can get the `current url` but I can't figure it out how to add the client's google profile name in `add people` section?

I found the above code here on this **[link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/)**.

PS: The client is not in my Google plus circle.